# jPlayer not working and no error in console

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, jplayer

I am using [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) on my website but it is not working and there is no error in console to debug as well
All files are included in correct order
**Header**

```
<script data-main="/scripts/main" src="{{ URL::asset('scripts/require.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('scripts/jquery.js')}}"></script>
```

**Index**

```
<li>
  <div class="userPhoto"> <img src="images/artists/1.png"> </div>
  <div class="userSummary" > 
    <a href="/data/2.mp3" class="track" title="Ghoom Tana 1">d</a>
    <strong>
      <a href="#">
        John Doe
      </a>
    </strong>
    <span>
     <a href="#">Jazz</a> / <a href="#">Big Band</a>,
     <a href="#">Swing</a>
    </span> 
  </div>
  <div class="featuredPlayer">
    <span class="track-name"> </span><br>
    <div class="playerControls">
      <span class="jp-current-time"></span>
      <span class="jp-stop" title="Stop">Stop</span>
      <span class="jp-play" title="Play">Play</span>
      <span class="jp-pause" title="Pause">Pause</span>
      <span class="jp-duration"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thePlayer"><a href="#" class="likeIt" title="Like?">w</a></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
    $('.userPhoto img').each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    var $height = $this.height();
    console.log($height);
    $this.parent().parent().find(".featuredPlayer").css("height", $height);
});


$('.userSummary > a').click(function () {

    $(this).parents().find('.featuredPlayer').addClass('show');
    $(this).parents().siblings().find('.featuredPlayer').removeClass('show');

});


$('.jp-stop').click(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.featuredPlayer').removeClass('show');
});

var container = $('nav#left').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: false,
    autoReinitialise: false
});
var jsp = container.data('jsp');

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    jsp.reinitialise();
});

// Local copy of jQuery selectors, for performance.
var my_jPlayer = $("#jquery_jplayer"),
        my_trackName = $("#jp_container .track-name"),
        my_playState = $("#jp_container .play-state"),
        my_extraPlayInfo = $("#jp_container .extra-play-info");

// Some options
var opt_play_first = false, // If true, will attempt to auto-play the default track on page loads. No effect on mobile devices, like iOS.
        opt_auto_play = true, // If true, when a track is selected, it will auto-play.
        opt_text_playing = "Now playing", // Text when playing
        opt_text_selected = "Track selected"; // Text when not playing

// A flag to capture the first track
var first_track = true;

// Change the time format
$.jPlayer.timeFormat.padMin = true;
$.jPlayer.timeFormat.padSec = true;
//  $.jPlayer.timeFormat.sepMin = " min ";
//  $.jPlayer.timeFormat.sepSec = " sec";

// Initialize the play state text
my_playState.text(opt_text_selected);

// Instance jPlayer
my_jPlayer.jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $("#jp_container .track-default").click();
    },
    timeupdate: function (event) {
        my_extraPlayInfo.text(parseInt(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute, 10) + "%");
    },
    play: function (event) {
        my_playState.text(opt_text_playing);
    },
    pause: function (event) {
        my_playState.text(opt_text_selected);
    },
    ended: function (event) {
        my_playState.text(opt_text_selected);
    },
    //swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    smoothPlayBar: true
});

// Create click handlers for the different tracks
$("#jp_container .track").click(function (e) {
    my_trackName.text($(this).attr('title'));
    my_jPlayer.jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: $(this).attr("href")
    });

    my_jPlayer.jPlayer("play");

    first_track = false;
    $(this).blur();
    return false;
});

$('.profilePlaylist ul li ul li a.track').click(function (e) {

    $('.profilePlaylist ul li ul').removeClass('playing');

    var playing = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('ul');

    var notplaying = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('ul.playing');

    playing.toggleClass('playing');

    notplaying.toggleClass('playing');

    e.preventDefault();
});


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment.

Your jPlayer is using `$("#jquery_jplayer")`, but there is nothing in your html specifying this. Have you left this out or am I missing something?

The same goes for `$("#jp_container .track-default").click();` You don't have track-default element in your html. Where are you specifying the default tracks for your jPlayer?

Maybe this can help: http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/19717/

If I am missing something please tell me. Or if you can post full HTML with classes you are using in jquery that would be better. A Jsfiddle would be great if you could.